# Comment editor appears multiple times

Tags: bug, comments, editor

when I click various times on "edit" next to my comment, the editor appears multiple times (the second time there are two editors in the first box and another one at the bottom and the third time there are three editors in the first box etc.)

See this screenshot:

[image: grafik.png]

Comment: @AnneDaunted Ok, looks the same. That bug report wasn't suggested to me and I couldn't find it via search.

Comment: Your duplicate helps others who happen to use the same keywords as you find the canonical report.